# How to know my neural network model's accuracy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have trained my neural network model. I want to know my model's accuracy from this training epoch. Do I have to get the average or just the last one?
here's my output

````
25/25 - 12s - loss: 1.3415 - accuracy: 0.3800 - val_loss: 1.0626 - val_accuracy: 0.5000
Epoch 2/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 1.0254 - accuracy: 0.5000 - val_loss: 1.1129 - val_accuracy: 0.4000
Epoch 3/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.9160 - accuracy: 0.6500 - val_loss: 0.8640 - val_accuracy: 0.7000
Epoch 4/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.8237 - accuracy: 0.6300 - val_loss: 0.8494 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 5/20
25/25 - 11s - loss: 0.7411 - accuracy: 0.7320 - val_loss: 0.7320 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 6/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.7625 - accuracy: 0.6600 - val_loss: 1.0259 - val_accuracy: 0.6000
Epoch 7/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.8317 - accuracy: 0.6800 - val_loss: 0.5907 - val_accuracy: 0.7500
Epoch 8/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.5557 - accuracy: 0.8100 - val_loss: 0.4630 - val_accuracy: 0.9000
Epoch 9/20
25/25 - 11s - loss: 0.6640 - accuracy: 0.7629 - val_loss: 0.3308 - val_accuracy: 0.9500
Epoch 10/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.5674 - accuracy: 0.8200 - val_loss: 0.5039 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 11/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.5566 - accuracy: 0.8200 - val_loss: 0.2161 - val_accuracy: 0.9500
Epoch 12/20
25/25 - 16s - loss: 0.5190 - accuracy: 0.8400 - val_loss: 0.3210 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 13/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.5437 - accuracy: 0.7800 - val_loss: 0.7253 - val_accuracy: 0.6500
Epoch 14/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.5035 - accuracy: 0.8300 - val_loss: 0.4291 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 15/20
25/25 - 11s - loss: 0.4276 - accuracy: 0.8600 - val_loss: 0.2902 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 16/20
25/25 - 11s - loss: 0.4913 - accuracy: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.3027 - val_accuracy: 0.9000
Epoch 17/20
25/25 - 11s - loss: 0.2931 - accuracy: 0.9100 - val_loss: 0.2718 - val_accuracy: 0.9000
Epoch 18/20
25/25 - 11s - loss: 0.4554 - accuracy: 0.8500 - val_loss: 0.4412 - val_accuracy: 0.8000
Epoch 19/20
25/25 - 11s - loss: 0.3803 - accuracy: 0.8400 - val_loss: 0.2479 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 20/20
25/25 - 12s - loss: 0.2692 - accuracy: 0.9200 - val_loss: 0.1805 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f64eec7ada0>```
````

Comment: Last epoch is considered as model accuracy. So as per above model training accuracy is 92% and validation accuracy is 100%

Comment: @H_J is that means over or underfitting?

Comment: Since validation accuracy is greater than training accuracy so I won’t think of over fitting. I am assuming you have enough population in both training and validation

Comment: In theory this would be considered overfitting. "In theory", because you seem to have only 20 samples in your validation set, far too few to tell that you are overfitting.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski I'm using `validation_split=0.3` and after I generate the data, I have 1533 train data and 655 validation data. Is that enough population?

Comment: It should be. That being said, you have pretty unlikely score for 655 data points. It's always a multiply of 0.05. It's out of topic anyway. For your question, check out my answer.

Comment: Since you have unselected my answer, it'd be helpful to know the reason. Feedback is essential to this community.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski sorry, it's an accident. The select is uncolored in my browser. So I click it again to make sure it is selected. But it just unselect it

Comment: Thanks, I thought that there's something wrong in the answer and wanted to fix that :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you train your model like this:

```
history = model.fit(...)
```

you can access accuracy through `history.history['acc']`. Other useful metrics:

- `loss` - loss
- `val_acc` - validation accuracy
- `val_loss` - validation loss

Last two are present only if you have validation set.